# Using switch in C#: how to complete the statement i'm trying to write?

Tags: c#

I am creating a program that calculates commission for staff based on the sales amount, I've got the commission calculations figured out, but I still need to write a switch statement to return "Please re-enter the sales amount" when any value other than a number is entered into the salesTextBox.

```
string empTitle;
double salesAmount;
double commAmt;

empTitle = employeeTextBox.Text;
salesAmount = double.Parse(salesTextBox.Text);
bool AmountIsNumber = double.TryParse(salesTextBox.Text, out salesAmount);

switch (empTitle)
{
    case "PT1":
        commAmt = (salesAmount * .1);
        MessageBox.Show(" The commission is " + commAmt.ToString());
        break;

    case "PT2":
        commAmt = (salesAmount * .15);
        MessageBox.Show(" The commission is " + commAmt.ToString());
        break;

    case "S1":
        commAmt = (salesAmount * .2);
        MessageBox.Show(" The commission is " + commAmt.ToString());
        break;

    case "S2":
        commAmt = (salesAmount * .25);
        MessageBox.Show(" The commission is " + commAmt.ToString());
        break;

    default:
        MessageBox.Show(" Please re-enter job title. ");
        break;
}

employeeTextBox.Clear();
salesTextBox.Clear();

switch (!AmountIsNumber)
{
}

MessageBox.Show(" Please re-enter the sales amount. ");
return;
```

Comment: It seems that you want an `if`, not a `switch` in that case.

Comment: Use `if...else...` condition in this case.

Comment: this statement `bool AmountIsNumber = double.TryParse(salesTextBox.Text, out salesAmount);` is useless and equal to `var AmountIsNumber = true;` because if `salesTextBox.Text` is not "parsable to" `double`, you will have `FormatException` thrown one line earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended but if you have to use `switch`

```
switch(!AmountIsNumber)
{
    case true: 
        MessageBox.Show(" Please re-enter the sales amount. ");
        break;
    case false:
        // your logic...
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but when I test it out i get an error at **salesAmount = double.Parse(salesTextBox.Text);**

Comment: @Evan That's a different question. You need to add a reference `using System.Globalization;` and then `double.TryParse(salesTextBox.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` Using `double.TryParse()` which converts the string representation of a number to its double-precision floating-point number equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded or failed. is highly recommended instead of `double.Parse()`.

Comment: just one thing: `using System.Globalization;` is a **using statement**, not **reference**

Comment: Curious why you switch on `!AmountIsNumber` instead of `AmountIsNumber`? Isn't the way you have it a little harder to read?

Answer (score 0):

To summarize all others answers:

1. You can't check `AmountIsNumber` in your first `switch` statement just because it is about `empTitle` and not about `salesAmount`.
2. Switch statement of `bool` is quite useless as it is easier to write

   ```
   if (condition)
       DoThis();
   else
       DoThat();
   ```

   then

   ```
   switch (condition)
   {
       case true:
           DoThis();
           break;
       case false:
           DoThat();
           break;
   }
   ```

As of your code, you may rewrite it this way:

```
double salesAmount, commAmt;
if (double.TryParse(salesTextBox.Text, out salesAmount))
{
    var message = ;
    switch (employeeTextBox.Text)
    {
        case "PT1":
            commAmt = (salesAmount * .1);
            break;
        case "PT2":
            commAmt = (salesAmount * .15);
            break;
        case "S1":
            commAmt = (salesAmount * .2);
            break;
        case "S2":
            commAmt = (salesAmount * .25);
            break;
        default:
            MessageBox.Show("Please re-enter job title.")
            return;
    }

    MessageBox.Show($"The commission is {commAmt}");
    employeeTextBox.Clear();
    salesTextBox.Clear();
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("Please re-enter the sales amount.");
```

Also, if need more codereview, there is [another stackexchange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for this.

**Suggestion 1:**

To be culture-neutral you need to replace `if (double.TryParse(salesTextBox.Text, out salesAmount))` with:

```
using System.Globalization;

// ...

var stringValue = salesTextBox.Text.Replace(',', '.');
if (double.TryParse(stringValue, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out salesAmount))
{
    // now we can safely parse "3.14" and "3,14" to 3.14
```

**Suggestion 2:**

If your `salesTextBox.Text` may contain only predefined values - it may be easier to use `ComboBox` control instead of `TextBox`:

```
// somewhere in designer or in the form/control constructor:
employeeComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;    
employeeComboBox.Items.AddRange(new object[] { "PT1", "PT2", "S1", "S2" });

// in your switch statement:
switch (employeeComboBox.SelectedItem)
{
    case "PT1":
        commAmt = (salesAmount * .1);
        break;
    case "PT2":
        commAmt = (salesAmount * .15);
        break;
    case "S1":
        commAmt = (salesAmount * .2);
        break;
    case "S2":
        commAmt = (salesAmount * .25);
        break;
    // now, we don't need the "default:" option here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done some refactoring on your code. I think this is what you want to write.

```
if (decimal.TryParse(salesTextBox.Text, out decimal salesAmount))
{
    Dictionary<string, decimal> commissions = new Dictionary<string, decimal>()
    {
        { "PT1", 0.1m },
        { "PT2", 0.11m },
        { "S1", 0.2m },
        { "S2", 0.25m },
    };

    string empTitle = employeeTextBox.Text;
    if (commissions.ContainsKey(empTitle))
    {
        decimal commAmt = salesAmount * commissions[empTitle];
        MessageBox.Show($" The commission is {commAmt}");
        employeeTextBox.Clear();
        salesTextBox.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" Please re-enter job title. ");
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(" Please re-enter the sales amount. ");
}
```

Please note that when working with currency amounts that it is better to use `decimal` (monetary values) rather than `double` (scientific values).

Answer (score 0):

You have an ambiguous syntax statements!
You've tried to parse out the text from a textbox then you've asked to tryParse out the same and asked it to out the result from the first statement which if it didn't work then it certainly won't work out again.

```
salesAmount = double.Parse(salesTextBox.Text);
bool AmountIsNumber = double.TryParse(salesTextBox.Text, out salesAmount);
```

This will no doubt be a problem.
You are better assigning the sales amount with a known value before trying to parse another value to it. As,

```
double salesAmount = -1;
double.TryParse(salesTextBox.Text, out salesAmount);
if (salesAmount != -1){
    //then ok its a number
}
else
{
    //its not a number
}
```